# Template Error: The template file must be given

Tags: linux, apache, cpanel, whm

I have a dev server that I'm running - I'm trying to point a different domain to this server...

for example - my dev server address would be like this:

http://dev.domain.com

Now I setup a subdomain on another domain name i have and have pointed the domain like this..

http://dev.newdomain.com

I didn't transfer the files, i simply made an A Record to point my new dev.newdomain.com at my old server IP on dev.domain.com so i don't have to transfer all the files

the only problem now is i'm receiving this error:

```
Template Error: The template file must be given
```

I have no clue how to fix this - I appreciate any help

I really hope that my description wasn't too confusing

Comment: Google? [The first result has a solution](http://www.linuxspy.info/tag/template-error-the-template-file-must-be-given/)

Comment: Yea - i saw that but cannot find the httpd.conf file to modify and i'm not sure if it will even work w/ the way i have the stuff setup

Comment: Not wanting to sound condescending, but did you have a look at the other results? [This looks promising](http://www.indianwebportal.com/template-error-template-file). Can you state what you've tried?

Comment: I did - however none of them seemed to match my scenario - it seemed all situations were dealing with the issue while being on the same domain and not switching domains like i am doing

Comment: I know this is a very old question, but I want to comment that the condescending answers here did not see the "cpanel" tag on the question. This is a cPanel problem. It has nothing at all to do with Apache. All the Google results assume that you are running Apache without cPanel and the relates "solutions" are useless. I have yet to figure out how to add a domain to cPanel and get it to work without this error.